# Dns protocol header

Tags: c, dns

I want to encode DNS protocol header using C and create a UDP datagram.
Lets say I have a query www.google.com.

Can anyone suggest how to go about it?

You can find the header format here - 
http://www.nersc.gov/~scottc/software/snort/dns_head.html

Comment: What is the problem?  Is it about C: How do I pack bits? Is it about the protocol: What are the opcode definitions?

Comment: Do you understand about the bitfields in a struct, how they are defined in C and so on?  The struct definition you mention is set up so you can simply make direct assignments to the bitfields.

Comment: Can someone point me to a tutorial or sample code which I can study

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) explains the DNS packet format in full detail. Note that the format is designed to be as compact as possible, so there are a lot of bit- and byte-level optimisations that you will have to pay attention to. A proper, robust DNS encoder and decoder is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Can you suggest any website or book where I can get any help

Comment: What do you need help with? Have you read and understood that RFC document?

Answer (score 2):

+1 to RFC 1035.
You can take a look on Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/
It shows packets in both - binary and decoded view + contains source code in C so you can check how decoding is implemented.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're pretty new here, so I thought I'd point out that "+1" means that you would click the up arrow beside a helpful post to increase its vote count. Others will do the same for your posts and that is how you gain reputation.

Comment: @Greg.  You know that the only way you can leave a comment before 50 rep is to make an answer, right?

Comment: thnx you for the help...I have installed wireshark and I am working on it now